# Gitlab behind Nginx and HTTPS -> insecure or bad gateway

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I'm running Gitlab behind my Nginx.

Server 1 (reverse proxy): Nginx with HTTPS enabled and following config for `/git`:

```
location ^~ /git/ {
    proxy_pass                          http://134.103.176.101:80;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
}
```

If I dont change anything on my GitLab settings this will work but is not secure because of external http request like:

```
'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c1ca2b6e2cd20fda9d215fe429335e0e?s=120&d=identicon'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

so if I change the gitlab config on hidden server 2 (http gitlab):

```
external_url 'https://myurl'
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

as said in the docu. I will get a bad gateway error 502. with no page loaded.

what can I do ?

---

EDIT: Hacked it by setting:

```
gitlab_rails['gravatar_plain_url'] = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%{hash}?s=%{size}&d=identicon'
```

to https... this workes but is not a clean solution. (clone url is still http://)

Comment: Do you run a standalone nginx or the bundled version from gitlab omnibus instalation? In general: if you server e.g. gitlab via https and it includes at some point an image or gravater over http, it simply breaks the ssl encryption - no matter what you do. the gravatar service also serves its content via https. do you use any special settings for ssl / header-security?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its a standalone ngnix on a different server that is a reverse proxy with the location config i posted above. The gitlabserver has also a ngnix but I only changed the gitlab config file on this server. (fixed my text above for better understanding)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I run a similar setup and I ran into this problem as well. According to the [docs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#redirect-http-requests-to-https):

> By default, when you specify an external_url starting with 'https', Nginx will no longer listen for unencrypted HTTP traffic on port 80.

I see that you are forwarding your traffic over HTTP and port 80, but telling GitLab to use an HTTPS external URL. In this case, you need set the [listening port](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#setting-the-nginx-listen-port).

```rb
nginx['listen_port'] = 80   # or whatever port you're using.
```

Also, remember to reload the gitlab configuration after making changes to `gitlab.rb`. You do that with this command:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

---

For reference, here is how I do the redirect:

*Nginx config on the reverse proxy server:*

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;

    proxy_pass http://SERVER_2_IP:8888;
}
```

*The GitLab config file, `gitlab.rb`, on the GitLab server*:

```rb
external_url 'https://gitlab.domain.com'
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['SERVER_2_IP']
nginx['listen_port'] = 8888
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

Comment: I have almost the same setup and this helped me solve the issue of not being able to use https in the external_url value (which would cause nginx to look for certs and everything). Thanks!